# How to scrape multile parts of a single page with Python Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Given I have a single HTML file containing multiple sections with different structures that require widely different scraping. **What would be the best practices for the spider layout?**

Should I use one spider or more spiders? Should I request the same URL multiple times, each time with a different function for the callback? Or just sequentially parses the different parts? I ask in respect of being able to play nice with other parts of the framework — like *items* and *pipleines* — and also performance, limits and caching wise.

So, any best practice advise out there? Rules or conventions used in the community?

### Multiple Request

If I request a URL multiple times is it cached / throttled? Or do every request to the engine result in a request to the "external web server"?

```
class MultiSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    """Parse the parts in parallel."""

    name = 'multispider'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parser_01)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parser_02)

    def parser_01(self, response):
        selector = response.xpath('//some/path')
        if selector is not None:
            # do stuff with *selector* and
            yield {}

    def parser_0(self, response):
        selector = response.xpath('//some/other/path')
        if selector is not None:
            # do very different stuff with *selector* and
            yield {}
```

### Multiple Parser Functions

If I want to avoid a huge `parse` function and instead use multiple functions for different task / sections, are there especially good / bad ways to structure this (e.g. "how to yield from where")?

```
class SeqSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    """Parse the page sequentially."""

    name = 'seqspider'

    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', ]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = response.xpath('//some/path')
        if selector:
            yield from self.parser_01(response, selector):
        selector = response.xpath('//some/other/path')
        if selector:
            yield from self.parser_02(response, selector):

    def parser_01(self, response, selector):
        # do stuff with *selector* and
        yield {}

    def parser_0(self, response, selector):
        # do very different stuff with *selector* and
        yield {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question on how to structure a spider / best practices, here's what I'm usually doing:

1. Avoid building multiple spiders that work on the same pages - as the targeted website's bandwidth is usually the bottleneck and creating unnecessary traffic on the website isn't considered courteous scraping.
2. Same goes for creating multiple requests to the same URL: it might create unnecessary traffic to the target website, which isn't nice scraper behavior. Also scrapy by default filters duplicate requests so you might suddenly be wondering why not all of your requests are executed.

(Note: there are ways around this, also using proxies etc ... but that makes things unnecessary complicated)

3. So if you want to avoid big parse methods that do a lot of different things, feel free to split it up. Very similar to what you suggest in your own example. I would even go further and encapsulate complete processing steps into separate parse methods, e.g.

   ```
   class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

       def parse(self, response):
           yield self.parse_widgets_type_a(response)
           yield self.parse_widgets_type_b(response)
           # ....
           yield self.follow_interesting_links(response)

       def parse_widgets_type_a(self, response):
           # ....

       def parse_widgets_type_b(self, response):
           # ....

       def follow_interesting_links(self, response):
           # ....
           yield Request(interesting_url)
   ```

Based on this template you might even want to refactor the different parse methods into different Mixin Classes.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. But I have to use `yield from` in the `parse` function or I get `ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'generator'`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single page I would recommend to use one spider. Request the page once and parse all the data you need (You can use one or more functions for that).

I would also recommend to use Items, for example

```
import scrapy

class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
    product_name = scrapy.Field()
    product_asin = scrapy.Field()
    product_avg_stars = scrapy.Field()
    product_num_reviews = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

If you want to save your crawled data into a database you have should use the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I already use items and pipelines. Coming from Django, Scrapy is sweet to get started with. I tend to struggle more with common coding practice and things like that ;) Especially on how to structure my code to keep things clean, separated and hopefully not too inefficient.